# How to provide session data in direct_to_template or simple view in urls.py (without creating apps)

Tags: python, django

I'm working on a site where many pages don't need any logic and are rendered via direct_to_template in urls.py, like so:

```
url('^support/slp/$',
    direct_to_template, {
        'template': 'pages_fixed/support/support_slp.html',
        'extra_context': {
            'questions':  Question.objects.filter(show_slp=True).order_by('seq_num'),
            'user_state': request.session['user_state'],   # <-- tried adding, no go
        }
    },
    name='support'
),
```

A new requirement came up which requires me to check the state of a session var in most of these pages, to render different bits of the template. I tried supplying the request object but obviously, it's not available in the urls.

I know that I can try creating a new 'app' for each such page (or, say, category of pages) and then provide the session var in each view.py view function. However, this seems really excessive given how many pages there are, and I only need this one var available.

What would be the simplest (most light-weight) solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its about time you started using the [generic class based views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/class-based-views/), which will automatically pass in the *request context*, which will make session data available in your templates.

You will have to enable the template [request context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/templates/api/#django-core-context-processors-request) which will give you a `{{ request }}` variable at the template level.

Here is an example using [`ListView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#django.views.generic.list.ListView):

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns
from django.views.generic.list import ListView

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^support/slp/$',
        ListView.as_view(template_name="pages_fixed/support/support_slp.html",
                         queryset=Question.objects.filter(show_slp=True).order_by('seq_num')),
)
```

In your `support_slp.html` template, you'll have a `object_list` variable that will be result of the queryset and you can use `{{ request.session.user_state }}` in the template.

Comment: I use Class-based views in my apps but my hope was not having to create new Django apps for all these legacy pages in this project. As I stated, there are quite a number of them. I will poke at these other answers but if I don't crack it, may end up doing just that..

Comment: This is not creating any apps, so what's the issue?

Comment: Well, your ListView example above would need to go into some views.py file within some 'app', isn't it? These pages I'm referring to do not have associated apps -- they're simply templates, rendered directly from urls.py. Can you please clarify?

Comment: This code is all in urls.py not in some views. The code I pasted, is the exact code you need; without any views.

Comment: Jeez, indeed. Didn't know request.session was available like this (was already enabled in my TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This could easily be done in a custom template tag. Inclusion and assignment tags can optionally accept the existing context, which includes the request if you have the request context processor activated. You can use that to access the session.

Comment: Thanks. Sounds like what I need but haven't done much with custom tags. Any possibility getting an example?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a custom context processor to feed whatever you need into the context of all the pages. Suppose you put this code in package_name/context_processors.py

```
def session_data(request):
    return {
        'user_state': request.session['user_state'],
    }
```

The you specify this context processor in `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` in the settings file:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
    'django.core.context_processors.debug',
    'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
    'django.core.context_processors.media',
    'django.core.context_processors.static',
    'django.core.context_processors.tz',
    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
    'package_name.context_processors.user_data')
```

More documentation on context processors available [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/settings/#std%3asetting-TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS)